Função .sortable() do jQuery para elementos criados de forma dinâmica
Estou desenvolvendo um projeto estilo kanban e estou tentando implementar uma função para ordenar os cards nas colunas conforme necessidade do usuário. Pensei em utilizar a função .sortable() do jQuery mas não está funcionando.
<div id="1" class="kanban-column">
          <div class="kanban-header media"> Lista de prioridade média</div>
          <div id="1" class"card">
              Texto de exemplo
           </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="kanban-column">
          <div class="kanban-header alta"> Lista de prioridade alta</div>
          <div id="2" class"card">
              Texto de exemplo para lista 2
           </div>
</div>

Seria uma estrutura assim, com as colunas/listas lado a lado e as colunas teriam suas tarefas/cards, podendo mudar a ordem dos cards de uma lista e movimentar o card de lista
$('.kanban-column').sortable({
  handle: '.card',
  animation: 150,
  axis: 'y',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('Card movido:', item);
    console.log('Nova posição:', item.index());
  },
});

Tentei fazer a ordenação dessa forma, e com códigos mais simples que isso, e ainda assim não consigo movimentar os cards nas colunas. Tendo essa ordem a ideia seria salvar a ordem, pensei em salvar a posição de cada card no banco de dados, mas essa forma não parece ser a melhor, em minha opinião

olá João, sugiro ver o exemplo que tem na documentação que é bem completo (clique no "View source"): https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists  Se não quiser usar listas (ul/li) basta substituir por div.  Outra coisa, remova da pergunta as tags que não relação com o probema (php, mysql)

Já tentei utilizar a função .sortable do jQuery, no entanto ainda não consegui utilizar ela em elementos criados de forma dinâmica

cada vez que gerar um novo elemento precisa fazer o $('.kanban-column').sortable novamente para poder rastrear nos novos elementos
